# Can't find interface declaration for my IOS view controller

Tags: ios, inheritance, header, superclass

I'm getting this error: "Cannot find interface declaration for 'BaseViewController', superclass of 'ViewController'. Here's the situation:

**AppDelegate:**

- Subclass of NSObject
- In the header file:

  `#include UIApplicationDelegate`

### BaseViewController

- Subclass of UIViewController
- In the header file:

  `#import "AppDelegate.h"`

### ViewController

- Subclass of BaseViewController

  `#import "BaseViewController.h"`

The error doesn't make sense, as `BaseViewController` is imported in `ViewController`'s header file. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cannot find interface declaration for 'BaseViewController'

That error means that the compiler can't find the line that looks like this:

@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController

But I think it CAN find the BaseViewController.h (Or it would complain about that specifically)

I'd check that the spelling is the same including upper/lowercase?

Other than that, it should work as you'd expect.

Comment: fixed it for me too. the problem was I was in a hurry and thought I was typing in the name of the class I wanted to make, when it was asking for the name of the parent class.

Comment: Wait, what is the fix here? I'm having the same problem, but my spelling of everything is correct.

Comment: @MusiGenesis , did you ever get to the bottom of why you were getting this error?  My spelling looks correct too.

Comment: it was an infinite loop in my #import statements.  How many more times am I going to make that mistake?

Comment: @kris: yeah, me too - it was a circular reference. My fix was to just move one of the references to one of the class' `.m` files (instead of having it in the header file).

Comment: You, Sir @MusiGenesis. You have just saved my day.

Answer (score 26):

Also check for infinite loops in your import statements

Answer (score 12):

Try adding

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```